# Finding a bound for x in epsilon delta continuity proofs

Tags: real-analysis

Consider a simple polynomial of the form f(x)=Ax^2+Bx+C from the Reals to the Reals.

One way to prove this is continuous involves finding a bound for x, which is done by supposing delta<=K, with K being some appropriate value.

My issue is this - if there are any discontinuities K distance away from any point in the function then that causes issues like dividing by an undefined quantity.

It seems to me then that what we're saying is the following:

If and only if f(x) is continuous then an appropriate K can be chosen to prove f(x) is continuous.

To prove f(x) is continuous we need to chose an appropriate K.

To choose an appropriate K we need to prove f(x) is continuous...

It very much appears to be circular reasoning, what am I messing up?

Answer (score 1):

The general procedure to proving continuity at a particular $x$ is: (1) fix an arbitrary $\epsilon$ (2) see if you can find a finite $\delta$ such that, for all $x'$ in the domain of $f$, $\vert x - x'\vert < \delta \Longrightarrow \vert f(x) - f(x') \vert < \epsilon$. Usually, for simple questions like this, you can guess a $\delta$ in terms of the arbitrary $\epsilon$ you fixed, e.g., set $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{2}$.

Your reasoning is certainly circular, you can't assume $f$ to be continuous in order to prove it's continuous!

If you don't need to prove directly using the delta-epsilon method, you can always say that the result of compositions and additions of continuous functions is continous, and only prove that $f(x) = x$ is continuous, which is simple enough to do.

Comment: Take x^3. Abs(f(x)-f(x')) = abs((x-x')(x^2+x'x+x'^2)) to get rid of the x's, suppose delta<=1, then -1<=x-x'<=1, x<=1+x', then set delta=min(1, e/(1+x')), putting that into what we had before we get abs((x-x')(x^2+x'x+x'^2))<=e/(1+x') * (1+x') = e. If (1+x') is a discontinuity anywhere, isn't this bunkem? How do I know it's not?

Comment: First thing is I suggest you format your question/comments in LaTeX, so that they are more readable and doing so helps others help you. Second, I suspect that you don't fully grasp the concept of epsilon-delta continuity proofs. Your question "if $(1+x')$ is a discontinuity anywhere" doesn't make sense in this context. You do not exactly need to care about what $x'$ is, it can be anything in the domain of $f$. You care about what happens at $x$ since you're trying to prove where $f$ is continuity at $x$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3579644/epsilon-delta-proof-for-continuity?rq=1 Check this out, should be helpful.

Comment: An edit to my previous comment, delta should be min(1, e/((1+x')^2+x'(1+x')+x'^2)). And sure it makes sense. Delta is being chosen as epsilon divided by the quotient of the function that has been evaluated at the bound found we found for x. It's (x-x')(q(1+x')). This is fine, as long as q(1+x') doesn't ever evaluate to a discontinuity, which if x^3 is continuous it won't. In general delta=min( 1, e/q(1+x')) will work for x^n+x^(n-1)...

Comment: I suppose if it did evaluate to a discontinuity, we could, in principle, just choose a closer point. But nothing this proof does proves that such a point exists - the function being continuous does.

Comment: Yes, usually the picture is that you choose **some arbitrary** $x'$ close to $x$. What you care about is the behavior **at** $x$, not what $x'$ is. In addition, typically you don't want $\delta$ to depend on $x'$. I suggest you review the definition and work through some easy examples on this.

Comment: Here's a prof going through the process I've talked about - https://youtu.be/BdCctrtttso He's found a bound for x by supposing delta<=1 and then evaluating the quotient at that bound. Delta is as I've indicated. Now let's say (-1,1) and (1,3) are undefined for x^3. To be clear "1" is defined. Delta=min(1, E/q(1+x')) and delta>0, therefore, there are no valid values around "1" for delta to be, nor should there be. I only know this, because I've defined it. How do I know there exists valid values anywhere else - the bound for x seems to require that the function be continuous to set that bound

Comment: I think I see where your confusion is. The method in that video is basically the same as the "dirty trick" or reverse-engineering @vonbrand talks about in the other answer. But the key point is that you have to reverse back when you write the proof, and this time, without assuming continuity at $x_0$ (as in his video), but because you did the reverse engineering step, you know a there exists a $\delta$ that works, so you show it.

Comment: Let's say f(x)=x^3 is only defined at f(x)=9. The process in the vid would show it's continuous everywhere f(x)=x^3 is with no arbitrary restrictions. It's basically, iff x^3 is continuous then I can do the reverse engineering process - how then can the reverse engineering process show that x^3 is continuous? Why isn't it circular? This is my issue :/

Comment: Usually when the question asks, "show $f$ is continuous at $x_0$/everywhere on its domain," it implies that yes indeed $f$ is continuous, so in this case, you can use the reverse engineering step. But if the question asks, "prove or disprove..." then you cannot start by thinking $f$ is continuous; using the reverse engineering method is fine, but you have to keep in mind that $f$ could be discontinous. Does this help?

Comment: I've been playing with this a little more and I think that finding a specific d for a specific ep around a specific point proves the continuity of these types of functions as much as the method for finding an arbitrary delta. Eg f(x)=x^3, e=1, d=0.0001, around f(3), shows there's a delta for every epsilon as much as the RE method - I think. As for why? I think, it's because the domain and codomain are the same, the completeness of R, the closure under the operations, the continuity of the operations, that each x maps to a y, all lead to behaviour around each point being the same - in a sense.

Comment: I think you need bijectivity for this to really hold... but I think you're on the right track

Comment: Oooh, that's interesting. Let s be an arbitrary value in the domain, and f: D—>R. Applying the function to an arbitrary interval f( (x-s, x+s) )= (f(x-s), f(x+s)). If f(x-s)<f(c)<f(x+s) exists, with c!=x such that (x-s)<c<(x+s) and there is a bijection between this interval and all other intervals, then the function is continuous. I don't think the implication necessarily holds in the other direction though.

Answer (score 0):

A dirty trick is to work backwards, i.e., tentatively pick some $\delta$ and see what the $\epsilon$ has to be, then see to reverse the reasoning. Often it turns out it makes the reasoning simpler if you add an extra constraint on $\delta$, like assuming it is less than $1$ or such.

In your case, take $p(x) = A x^2 + B x + C$, you want to prove that for all $\epsilon > 0$ there is a $\delta$ such that if $0 < \lvert x - x_0 \rvert \le \delta$ it is $\lvert p(x) - p(x_0) \rvert \le \epsilon$.

Pick $h \ne 0$, and compute:

$\begin{align*}
   \lvert p(x_0 + h) - p(x_0) \rvert
      &=   \lvert A ((x_0 + h)^2 - x_0^2)
                  + B (x_0 + h - x_0)
                  + C (1 - 1) \rvert \\
      &=   \lvert A (2 x_0 h + h^2) + B h \rvert
\end{align*}$

The mess is easier to handle if $\lvert h \rvert \le 1$, as so $h^2 \le \lvert h \rvert$, and you can simplify:

$\begin{align*}
   \lvert p(x_0 + h) - p(x_0) \rvert
      &\le   \lvert A (2 x_0 \lvert h \rvert + \lvert h \rvert ) + B \lvert h \rvert \rvert \\
      &\le   \lvert 2 A x_0 + A + B \rvert \cdot \lvert h \rvert
\end{align*}$

OK, time to track back.

Pick any $\epsilon > 0$, if you take $\delta = \min(1, \epsilon / \lvert 2 A x_0 + A + B \rvert)$ you can turn around the reasoning for any $\lvert h \rvert \le \delta$.

In any case, for polynomials it is much nicer to use the (easy to prove) continuity of $f(x) \cdot g(x)$, $f(x) + g(x)$ and $c f(x)$ at $x = x_0$ if $f, g$ are continuous at $x_0$. This leads easily to the continuity of $x^n$ for $n$ natural and thus polynomials by induction.

Comment: My issue isn't really finding delta, it's whether - https://youtu.be/BdCctrtttso is a circular argument. It seems like to set the bound for x it requires that f(x) is continuous and that a valid delta exists somewhere in that range. So, to use the bound I need to prove f(x) is continuous first.